# Problem using field calculator to add numbers in new field with preceding zeros

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

I wish to add a field in an attribute table that should work as a georeferencing key. It needs to take into consideration values from a series of fields. The last field is a housenumber and it contains from one to five digits (e.g. 2, 20, 20A, 200A, 200AB etc.) What shall I write in Field calculator to ensure that the above housenumbers becomes the following values in my new field:
002
020
020A
200A
200AB

So that the numbers are always represented with 3 digits (containing preceding zeros if necessary), and possible subsequent letters are kept?

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple approach using the built-in Python `.isdigit()`, `.isalpha()` and `.zfill()` methods.  This approach uses the Python parser.

---

Pre-logic Script Code:

```
def changeAddress(y):
  integer = ''.join(x for x in y if x.isdigit())
  string = ''.join(x for x in y if x.isalpha())
  final = integer.zfill(3)
  return final + string
```

---

```
changeAddress(!YourField!)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to calculate this, one is using regexp with Python:

expression:

```
value(!f!)
```

code block:

```
def value(f):
 import re
 if len(re.findall(r'\d', f)) ==1:
  return "00{}".format(f)
 elif len(re.findall(r'\d', f)) ==2:
  return "0{}".format(f)
 else:
  return f
```

[image]