# Converting field to string with leading zeroes using Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I would like to create an expression using the field calculator in ArcMap to be able to convert an Int field to a string and add leading zeroes.

I am able to do it in a python window with an example

```
x=450
print str(x).zfill(4)
>>>0450
```

I have tried:

```
!Time!.str().zfill(4)
```

but that gives me invalid syntax errors.

Comment: Here is a similar question answered earlier today: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129927/problem-using-field-calculator-to-add-numbers-in-new-field-with-preceding-zeros

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str` is a class, not a method, so you need to do:

```
str(!Time!).zfill(4)
```

This should work if the `Time` field is an integer. If it's a `float` or other type, you will need to recast it as an `int`.